# What is the way to use a Locale (known from a web page or REST service), in a Spring boot 2 @Service and in the Business Objects / POJOs it uses?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a common problem. A end user either uses a web page or call a REST web-service. The controller knows his locale : let say : `fr_FR`. Then the controller call a service and use business objects, but those are defaulting to another locale because they are not aware of the Locale received by the controller.

In my example, a not clever customer asks a carpenter to remove a back panel from a chair. The chair, as a modern business object, has the ability to autocheck itself about its state and will eventually be unhappy :

On a web site, the customer asks : "*Monsieur le menuisier, sciez-moi donc cela, sur cette chaise.*" (fr)

A method from a *CarpenterService* (a class anotated by `@Service` on `Spring`) is called. It wants to warn, while doing the job.

```
public void doTheJob(Chair chair) {
...
   deliveryNote.warn(ResourceBundle.getBundle(..).getString("beware"));
   // it warns : "Dear customer, it seems to me that you are doing a mistake." (en)
   // instead of : "Cher client, il me semble que vous faites une bêtise." (fr)
   ...
   if (chair.autocheck() == false) {
      deliveryNote.warn(chair.complain());
      // It warns : "I am not a chair but a stool : I have no chair back." (en)
      // instead of : "Je ne suis pas une chaise mais un tabouret : je n'ai pas de dossier."
   }
   ...
}
```

The REST or web controller knows the locale `fr_FR`. But not the `@Service` or the POJO who are defaulting to `en_US`.

The only way I know to ensure using the same locale at any layer is to carry it  in parameter in the carpenter service methods and create a method receiving also a Locale in the POJO. But really, it's clumsy...

Is there a better way to handle this kind of problem now, using Spring boot 2 ?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: A solution, which is not spring boot 2 specific, would be to use a [ThreadLocal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) variable to store/retrieve the locale. You would have something like a ContextHolder with a static ThreadLocal field and with getLocale/setLocale methods, then in the REST controller set the locale in the ContextHolder and in the service read the locale from the ContextHolder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LocaleContextHolder` in your `@Service` class to retrieve the `locale`

Spring documentation for this class:

> Simple holder class that associates a LocaleContext instance with the current thread. The LocaleContext will be inherited by any child threads spawned by the current thread if the inheritable flag is set to true.
>   Used as a central holder for the current Locale in Spring, wherever necessary: for example, in MessageSourceAccessor. DispatcherServlet automatically exposes its current Locale here. Other applications can expose theirs too, to make classes like MessageSourceAccessor automatically use that Locale.

So in your example

```
public void doTheJob(Chair chair) {
    Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
    deliveryNote.warn(ResourceBundle.getBundle("baseName", locale).getString("beware"));
    ...
}
```

Comment: I have to say that its really, really clean, and I am very satisfied because it will remove me a bunch of parameter transportation. But what about if one of the components might broke the chain ? For example : I have a service `A` that calls a service `B` that use `Spark` (who creates many threads) who uses a service `C` I provide. `A` and `B` will share the same Locale by the mean of the `LocaleContextHolder`. But will `C` know it ?